# Contact Form 7 - Populating dropdown list with terms relative to the post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, plugin-contact-form-7

I found another post that had the code for dynamically populating a CF7 dropdown with the terms of a taxonomy, and I have it working, but I wanted the terms to not just be all within the taxonomy, but I wanted them to only be relative to the post that it's on.

To give it some more context, this is an application form on a job posting. The custom post type are job listings. I have a taxonomy of locations. Those terms are assigned to a post. I want only the selected terms to appear in this dropdown.

This is the code I have:

```
function dynamic_select_list( $tag ) {

    // Only run on select lists
    if( 'select' !== $tag['type'] && ('select*' !== $tag['type']) ) {
        return $tag;
    } else if ( empty( $tag['options'] ) ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    $term_args = array();

    // Loop thorugh options to look for our custom options
    foreach( $tag['options'] as $option ) {

        $matches = explode( ':', $option );

        if( ! empty( $matches ) ) {

            switch( $matches[0] ) {

                case 'taxonomy':
                    $term_args['taxonomy'] = $matches[1];
                    break;

                case 'parent':
                    $term_args['parent'] = intval( $matches[1] );
                    break;

            }
        }

    }

    // Ensure we have a term arguments to work with
    if( empty( $term_args ) ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    // Merge dynamic arguments with static arguments
    $term_args = array_merge( $term_args, array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $terms = get_terms( $term_args );

    // Add terms to values
    if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

        foreach( $terms as $term ) {

            $tag['values'][] = $term->name;

        }

    }

    return $tag;

}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_select_list', 10 );
```

Comment: have you tried to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/ ?

Comment: @Michael I am unsure of how to tie that into cf7

Comment: I am referring to this one line in your posted code: `    $terms = get_terms( $term_args );` - PS: have you asked in the plugin's forum?

Comment: Replaced `$terms = get_terms( $term_args );` with `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'location_categories' );` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dynamic_dropdown tag functionality offered by the [Smart Grid layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/).  The dynamic tag can take 3 sources of data (a given taxonomy, or branch within that taxonomy, a list of post titles, or the results of a filtered hook function).  Use the filter hook to populated your dropdown as,

```
add_filter('cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options', 'filter_options',10,3);
function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
  if($form_key != 'my-form') return $options; //check this is the correct form.
  if($field_name != 'custom-dropdown') return $options; //check this is the correct field.
  $options = array(); 
  //get your terms
  $terms = get_terms( $term_args );
  // Add terms to values
  if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
      //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
      $options[$term->id] = $term->name;
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how to use this function?
I have this text created by the dynamic dropdown option, and I would like to populate the dropdown with data from mysql table:
```php
add_filter( 'cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options','dynamic_select_352_dynamic_options',10,3);
/**
* Filter dropdown options for dynamic drodpwn list of taxonomy terms.
* @param mixed $options the opttion to filter.
* @param string $name the field name being populated.
* @param string $cf7_key the form unique key.
* @return mixed $options return either an array of <option value>=><option label> pairs or a html string of opti

Comment: Hi - you've posted this an answer to an existing question whereas it looks like it's a new question? But if you meant where to put this code, it needs to go in a new plugin or in your theme's functions.php file (assuming you have your own theme or a child theme, so that changes to the theme won't get lost by a theme update)

Comment: @Kai do not post a question as a solution to an old question. If you have a question, use the "Ask Question" button