# Filter multiple dynamic dropdown lists within one form using the Smart Grid-layout extension for Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, select

I recently [found solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358736/contact-form-7-populating-dropdown-list-with-terms-relative-to-the-post/367134#367134) for populating dropdown list with terms relative to the post. Everything works but I need to use this code on multiple dropdown lists within one form.

My code looks something like this but it doesn’t work, can you help me with that? Thank you.

```
add_filter('cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options', 'filter_options',10,3);
function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
 if($form_key != 'bez-nazvu') return $options; //check this is the correct form.
 if($field_name != 'dynamic_select-461') return $options; //check this is the correct field.
 $options = array(); 
 //get your terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'strava' );
 if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

   foreach( $terms as $term ) {
     //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
     $options[$term->name] = $term->name;
   }
 }  return $options;
 
} 

function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
 if($form_key != 'bez-nazvu') return $options; //check this is the correct form.
 if($field_name != 'dynamic_select-462') return $options; //check this is the correct field.
 $options = array(); 
 //get your terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'doprava' );
 if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

   foreach( $terms as $term ) {
     //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
     $options[$term->name] = $term->name;
   }
 }  return $options;
 
} 

function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
 if($form_key != 'bez-nazvu') return $options; //check this is the correct form.
 if($field_name != 'dynamic_select-463') return $options; //check this is the correct field.
 $options = array(); 
 //get your terms
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'terminy' );
 if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

   foreach( $terms as $term ) {
     //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
     $options[$term->name] = $term->name;
   }
 }  return $options;
 
}
```

Comment: you are erroneously using the php filter coding mechanism.  Every `add_filter` hook must call a single and unique function, you are trying to call 3 functions!  Please read this [tutorial](https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/26-wordpress-actions-filters-and-hooks-a-guide-for-non-developers) on how to use php hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead, combine all 3 functions into a single one,

```
add_filter('cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options', 'filter_options',10,3);
function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
  //field 'dynamic_select-461'
  if($form_key == 'bez-nazvu' && $field_name == 'dynamic_select-461') {
    $options = array(); 
    //get your terms
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'strava' );
    if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

      foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
        $options[$term->name] = $term->name;
      }
    }
  }
  //field 'dynamic_select-462'
  if($form_key == 'bez-nazvu' && $field_name == 'dynamic_select-462') {
   $options = array(); 
   //get your terms
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'doprava' );
   if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {

     foreach( $terms as $term ) {
       //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
       $options[$term->name] = $term->name;
     }
   }  
  } 
 //field 'dynamic_select-463'
 if($form_key == 'bez-nazvu' && $field_name == 'dynamic_select-463') {
   $options = array(); 
   //get your terms
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'terminy' );
   if( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_args ) ) {
     foreach( $terms as $term ) {
       //this is the <option value="">label</opton> value->label pairs.
       $options[$term->name] = $term->name;
     }
   }  
   
  }
  return $options;
}
```